# Rake aborted during postgresql migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rake

Rails/PostgreSQL newbie here, having real problems dealing with creating PostgreSQL projects in Rails.

Briefly, I am following Ryans excellent Railscast episodes, in particular the episode on deployment. I create a new project like this:

```
rails new blog -d postgresql
```

This generates a `database.yml` file similar to the following (comments extracted):

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: blog_development
  pool: 5
  username: blog
  password:

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: blog_test
  pool: 5
  username: blog
  password:

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: blog_production
  pool: 5
  username: blog
  password:
```

Looks good so far.

However, on my development machine, whenever I try to run `rake db:create:all`, I get a message similar to the following:

```
rake aborted!
FATAL: role "blog" does not exist
```

My understanding is that this is because I haven't (or, rather, Rails hasn't) created a user called "blog" when the application was created. Therefore, I need to either:

1. Change the `username` for all environments to my system's "super
   user" I chose when I installed Homebrew (which works); OR
2. Create a new super user for each individual project I set up (e.g. a
   super user "blog" in this instance).

Now, the problem is this - should I be creating a super user for each individual project I create? If so, how? The reason I ask is that Ryan's Railscasts episodes never actually mention this, so I'm not sure if this is the correct approach to be taking (it seems a bit long-winded), or if there is a problem with my PostgreSQL database installation (as I would have thought that the super user would be automatically set up along with the database when the application is created).

Additionally, so as to make deployment easier, I'd like to keep the overall `database.yml` file the same in both the development and production environments (although I admit to knowing even less about deployment, so maybe this isn't ideal).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating database users is up to you. Rails does not create database users.

Depending on your platform, you can use some kind of database management GUI to make it easier to create users and manage their rights. I use PGAdmin, which came with the Mac OS X executable for PostgreSQL. It is available for other platforms as well.

In development, many people use the same "superuser" for all projects. In production, I would advice you to have application-specific users with minimal privileges.

I don't exactly understand the last paragraph about the `database.yml` being the same for dev and prod envs, because that is precisely the point - one file for all environments. You should probably not use the same credentials for development and production.

Comment: Thanks Jesper. I tend to use my "local" username in development mode for development and test environments. I do plan to have a separate production user set up on the server database, but when I run db:migrate locally, it won't find the user on my local machine so it will throw the error message (I think). Should I be setting up a "production" super-user locally as well, with the same credentials as the super-user on the server?

Comment: About superusers: on your local machine, for simplicity and speed in development, you can use a superuser account as your database role. On the production and would advice you not to use a superuser account as the account that Rails uses to access the database. So in a way, superusers are out of the scope of the Rails part of this discussion. It seems clear that what you need to do next is to read up on user/roles in PG and then create an appropriate role on your local machine.